# Get value from one of the input tags

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a few donation forms on one page. The condition of which form will be shown is defined through variable data-selected="true". I wrote down a script to get the amount of donation from radio or field, so I could send this data through GTM to GA4, but it doesn`t work. Check my and point out my mistake, please

HTML from where I try to get value

```
 <div class="donate-form">
                    <div class="donate-form_tabs" id="donate_tabs">
                        <button class="page-action-text donate-form_tabs_action" type="button" data-value="donate_monthly" data-selected="true">
                            {{ __('donate.monthly_tab_action') }}
                        </button>
                        <button class="page-action-text donate-form_tabs_action" type="button" data-value="donate_single" data-selected="false">
                            {{ __('donate.single_tab_action') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <form id="donate-single-form" class="donate-single-form donate-form_tabs_content" data-tab="donate_single" data-selected="false">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="page-text page-text-bold donate-single-title">{{ __('donate.single_title') }}</div>
                                <div class="donate-single">
                                    <div class="donate-form_radio_group">
                                        <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                            <input class="_form_amount" value="50" id="donate_s_50" type="radio" name="sum">
                                            <label for="donate_s_50">
                                                50
                                                <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                            <input class="_form_amount" value="100" id="donate_s_100" type="radio" name="sum">
                                            <label for="donate_s_100">
                                                100
                                                <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                            <input class="_form_amount" value="200" id="donate_s_200" type="radio" name="sum" checked>
                                            <label for="donate_s_200">
                                                200
                                                <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                            <input class="_form_amount" value="500" id="donate_s_500" type="radio" name="sum">
                                            <label for="donate_s_500">
                                                500
                                                <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                            <input class="_form_amount" value="700" id="donate_s_700" type="radio" name="sum">
                                            <label for="donate_s_700">
                                                700
                                                <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="donate-form_input">
                                        <input type="number" placeholder="{{ __('donate.amount_other') }}" id="diff_sum1" min="50" class="_form_amount_other">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>  
                            
                            <div>
                                <div class="donate-email">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="{{ __('donate.email') }}" class="_form_email" required>
                                    <span class="donate-email-message">{{ __('donate.email_message') }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>    
                    </form>

                    <form id="donate-monthly-form" class="donate-monthly-form donate-form_tabs_content" data-tab="donate_monthly" data-selected="true">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="donate-monthly-tabs">
                                    <div class="donate-monthly-tabs-action" data-value="friend" data-selected="true">
                                        <!-- <div class="donate-monthly-tabs-action-subtitle"> 500 </div> -->
                                        <h2 class="donate-monthly-tabs-action-title">{{ __('donate.monthly_friend_title') }}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="donate-monthly-tabs-action" data-value="bro" data-disabled="true">
                                        <!-- <div class="donate-monthly-tabs-action-subtitle"> 500 </div> -->
                                        <h2 class="donate-monthly-tabs-action-title">{{ __('donate.monthly_bro_title') }}</h2>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
        
                                <div class="donate-monthly_container">
                                    <div class="donate-monthly" data-selected="true" data-value="friend">
                                        <div class="donate-monthly-content">
                                            <h2 class="donate-monthly-title">{{ __('donate.monthly_friend_title') }}</h2>
                
                                            <div class="donate-monthly-list">
                                                <div>
                                                    <img class="donate-monthly-list-icon" src="{{ asset('images/client/icons/ico-message-circle.svg') }}" alt="">
                                                    {{ __('donate.monthly_friend_feat_1') }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <img class="donate-monthly-list-icon" src="{{ asset('images/client/icons/ico-mail.svg') }}" alt="">
                                                    {{ __('donate.monthly_friend_feat_2') }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <img class="donate-monthly-list-icon" src="{{ asset('images/client/icons/ico-edit.svg') }}" alt="">
                                                    {{ __('donate.monthly_friend_feat_3') }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                
                                            <div class="donate-form_radio_group">
                                                <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                                    <input class="_form_amount" value="200" id="donate_m_200" type="radio" name="sum">
                                                    <label for="donate_m_200">

                                                        200
                                                        <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                                    <input class="_form_amount" value="500" id="donate_m_500" type="radio" name="sum" checked>
                                                    <label for="donate_m_500">
                                                        500
                                                        <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                                    <input class="_form_amount" value="1000" id="donate_m_1000" type="radio" name="sum">
                                                    <label for="donate_m_1000">
                                                        1000
                                                        <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="donate-form_input">
                                                <input type="number" placeholder="{{ __('donate.amount_other') }}" id="diff_sum1" min="50" class="_form_amount_other">
                                                <!-- temporary disable bro -->
                                                <!-- <div class="donate-form_input_hint"> 500 </div> -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- temporary disable bro -->
                                    <div class="donate-monthly" data-value="bro" data-disabled='true'>
                                        <div class="donate-monthly-content">    
                                            <div class="donate-monthly-title">{{ __('donate.monthly_bro_title') }}</div>
        
                                            <div class="donate-monthly-list">
                                                <div>
                                                    <img class="donate-monthly-list-icon" src="{{ asset('images/client/icons/ico-message-circle.svg') }}" alt="">
                                                    {{ __('donate.monthly_bro_feat_1') }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <img class="donate-monthly-list-icon" src="{{ asset('images/client/icons/ico-mail.svg') }}" alt="">
                                                    {{ __('donate.monthly_bro_feat_2') }}
                                                </div>
                                                <div>
                                                    <img class="donate-monthly-list-icon" src="{{ asset('images/client/icons/ico-edit.svg') }}" alt="">
                                                    {{ __('donate.monthly_bro_feat_3') }}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
        
                                            <div class="donate-form_radio_group">
                                                <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                                    <input class="_form_amount" value="500" id="donate_m_500" type="radio" name="sum">
                                                    <label for="donate_m_500">
                                                        500
                                                        <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                                    <input class="_form_amount" value="700" id="donate_m_700" type="radio" name="sum">
                                                    <label for="donate_m_700">
                                                        700
                                                        <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="donate-form_radio">
                                                    <input class="_form_amount" value="1000" id="donate_m_1000" type="radio" name="sum">
                                                    <label for="donate_m_1000">
                                                        1000
                                                        <span>{{ __('donate.uah') }}</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="donate-form_input">
                                                <input type="number" placeholder="{{ __('donate.amount_other') }}" id="diff_sum2" min="500" class="_form_amount_other">
                                                <!-- <div class="donate-form_input_hint"> 500 </div> -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> 

                            <div>
                                <div class="donate-email">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="{{ __('donate.email') }}" class="_form_email" required>
                                    <span class="donate-email-message">{{ __('donate.email_message') }}</span>
                                </div>

                                    <button class="btn btn--green donate__btn" type="submit" id="donate_monthly">{{ __('donate.monthly_support_button') }}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                    </form>
                </div>
```

The script, which should get needed values

```
function() {
  if(document.querySelectorAll("form.[data-selected]='true'").getElementById("diff_sum1") === ""){
    var el = document.querySelectorAll("form.[data-selected]='true'").querySelector('[name="sum"]:checked')
    if (el) {
        return el.value
    }
  }
  else if (document.querySelectorAll("form.[data-selected]='true'").getElementById("diff_sum1") !== "") {
      var el = document.getElementById("diff_sum")
      if (el) {
          return el.value
      }
  }
   else {
      var el = document.getElementById("diff_sum2")
      if (el) {
          return el.value
   }
  }
}
```